# Dojo mobile ScrollableView not scrolling on blackberry when using mouse

Tags: blackberry, dojo, mousewheel, dojox.mobile

I'm using dojo 1.9.2 and have developed a mobile browser app.
The app works fine on iOS and Andriod, but the Blackberry is an issue.

All my pages consist of a **dojox/mobile/ScrollableView** with very basic content (RoundedRectlist, and RoundedRect as examples)

The problem is that all the content that needs to scroll, only scrolls with the touch events, and nothing happens when the user uses the "Blackberry Mouse".

Device I'm testing on:
** **Mozilla/5.0 (BlackBerry; U; BlackBerry 9900; en) AppleWebKit/534.11+ (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/7.0.0.296 Mobile Safari/534.11+** **

Can anybody please tell me how to make this work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess that by "Blackberry mouse" you refer to the trackpad that was present on models such as BB Torch 9860.

I think the key thing here is that, per design of these devices, the swipe gesture using the trackpad serves a different purpose: performing browser scroll at the level of the entire page. You can see such scroll active using the trackpad when the page is overflowing the screen size. Differently, the scrolling at the level of dojox/mobile/ScrollableView often concerns only part of the screen (the remaining being for instance headers and/or footers), and there can even be more than one scrollable area inside the page. Hence, it wouldn't be practical to scroll them using the trackpad, since it would first require to identify the element which should scroll - for that you'd need to click it, which may wrongly trigger a button action for instance.

Try for instance to scroll using the trackpad on this BB sample page: http://blackberry.github.io/WebWorks-Samples/kitchenSink/html/css3/overflow.html. It contains several scrollable areas, and the trackpad only allows to scroll the entire page, not the individual scrolling elements.

If in your dojox/mobile app you don't need fixed headers or footers, just use a dojox/mobile/View instead of ScrollableView. This way the content can overflow the page size, and you'll be able to scroll the entire page using the BB trackpad.

All in one, I think the behavior you observe is the expected one.

Comment: Thanks, I see what you mean. It makes sense in someway.